# Can you make Julia's readdir() function differentiate files from directories?

Tags: julia, readdir

Julia's readir lists a directory but it doesn't say if the items are files or directories. Is there any way to toggle this?

Answer (score 3):

`readdir` gets the names of everything in the current directory. We can use [`isdir`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.isdir) or [`isfile`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.isfile) to filter it down.

```
# Get all directories
filter(isdir, readdir())
# Get all files
filter(isfile, readdir())
# Return a tuple consisting of the filename and whether or not it's a directory
map((x) -> (x, isdir(x)), readdir())
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned it was Windows, which won't accept all run commands, but got a full listing showing files and directories with  run(`cmd /C dir`)  - however, filter is more generally handy.

Comment: Looks like the editor removed the backticks from the run command.